# Kali linux taking super long to boot

Tags: kali-linux

I just installed kali linux ubuntu 64bit and its stuck on the dragon booting logo[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw8Bn.png)

and its just stuck for like 5 hours

Answer (score 0):

If it gets hung up on boot, one option is to try again, after making sure it has a boot device connected to the Mainboard